# Multiline regex. Match after sometimes present string

Tags: regex

I have a multiline string of

```
/ROC/42398492837498
/RFB/SOMETHING1
SOMETHING2
```

From which I want:

- no lines if they start with /ROC/
- the string that comes after /RFB/ if /RFB/ is present
- the entire string if neither of the above are met.

So from my examples, I would expect:

- No match
- `SOMETHING1`
- `SOMETHING2`

So far I have

```
^(?!\/ROC\/)(?:\/RFB\/)?.*$
```

However this matches the /RFB/ in line 2, presumably because of the optional ? and the following .*

Comment: You just need to group the `.*` at the end: `^(?!\/ROC\/)(?:\/RFB\/)?(.*)$`

Comment: See [this](https://regex101.com/r/rA3vS7/1).

Comment: What is the environment where you are using the regex? You need to capture the `(.*)` - it will be in Group 1.

Comment: just discovered "Non-capturing group" thanks to you guys. Powerfull !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a capturing group:

```
^(?!\/ROC\/)(?:\/RFB\/|)(.*)$
```

It will give you the following:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [25-35] `SOMETHING1`
MATCH 2
1.  [36-46] `SOMETHING2`
```

See it on  [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rA3vS7/1).